# compare two array with one subset of other in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have the below set of documents.
Is there a way to search for all document's that have the categories "61" and "64" (documents 1,2,3,5), no more or less?

```
  {"id": 1, "regions" : ["61", "64"]}
    {"id": 2, "regions" : ["61", "63", "64"]}
    {"id": 3, "regions" : ["67", "64", "61"]}
    {"id": 4, "regions" : ["61"]}
    {"id": 5, "regions" : ["61", "64"]}
```

Tnx in advance

Comment: Please do let me know if my answer works for you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "regions": {
        "query": "61 64",
        "operator": "AND"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out,

curl -u uname:'pword' -XGET 'host:port/index/type/_search?' -d '

```
{
  "filter": {
    "and": [
      {
        "in": {
          "regions": [
            "61"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "in": {
          "regions": [
            "64"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}'
```